# User select upload CSV file and delimit (text to columns)

Tags: excel, vba

can you please help me with the VBA code for user to select the csv file to upload and then use text to columns to delimit the values. I used the below code but it is pasting the values in a single row. the delimter is not working properly. Also the code is used for a different pattern. The pattern i want to delimit now is a simple 'COMMA' sepration. Can you please rectify my code?

```
Sub test()

    Dim fn, e
    Dim x, y, n As Long, txt As String, flg As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, a(), maxCol As Long
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("csv,*.csv", 1, "Open CSV", MultiSelect:=True)
    If Not IsArray(fn) Then Exit Sub
    n = 1
    For Each e In fn
    If FileLen(e) > 0 Then
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
    .OpenTextFile(e).ReadAll
    x = Split(txt, vbCrLf)
    ReDim a(1 To UBound(x) + 1, 1 To 20)
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
    y = Split(CleanCSV(x(i), Chr(2), Chr(3)), ",")
    maxCol = Application.Max(maxCol, UBound(y) + 2)
    If maxCol > UBound(a, 2) Then
    ReDim Preserve a(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To maxCol)
    End If
    For ii = 0 To UBound(y)
    a(i + 1, ii + 1) = y(ii)
    Next
    Next
    Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Resize(UBound(a, 1), maxCol).Value = a
    n = n + UBound(a, 1)
    End If
    Next
    With Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .Replace Chr(2), ",", xlPart
    .Replace Chr(3), vbNullString, xlPart
    End With
End Sub
 

Function CleanCSV(ByVal txt As String, ByVal subComma As String, _

  ByVal subDQ As String) As String
  Dim m As Object

 Static RegX As Object

 If RegX Is Nothing Then Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

 With RegX

 .Pattern = "(^|,)(""[^""]+"")(,|$)"

 Do While .test(txt)

 Set m = .Execute(txt)(0)

 txt = Application.Replace(txt, m.firstindex + 1, _

 m.Length, m.submatches(0) & Replace(Replace(m.submatches(1), _


 ",", subComma), """", subDQ) & m.submatches(2))

 Loop

 End With

 CleanCSV = txt


End Function
```

Comment: You need to debug and find out where the problems is.  We don't have your data, so it's difficult for us to say what the issue might be.  Also - please try to indent your code when posting, so folks can more easily follow what it's doing.

Comment: Apparently he took the code from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/change-format-of-data-imported-from-csv-file.752891/). I'd suggest to start from scratch instead of taking a code without any note and reverse engineering it. It should be simplier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised because when I use the code it works perfectly fine, did you try changing the n variable from 1 to another value? Try that and see if it still inputs it all in the same row. The code is complete whack and could be considered a write off but if it works, it works.